# Event not fired when button click

Tags: vb.net, events, button

I am writing a program to access the remote file data using FTP on button click event. Set breakpoint in the fist line of button click event. That program is using windows application
vb.net 2008.

If I run the application, when I click the button, it does not fire a click event of the button. Help me to correct.

Here's my code:

```
Dim reqFTP As FtpWebRequest
Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim filename1 As String
Dim ftpserverip As String
Dim ftpuserid As String
Dim ftpPassword As String
Try
    filename1 = TxtRemoteFile.Text
    filepath = TxtLocalFile.Text
    filename = Locfname.Text
    ftpserverip = TxtServerIP.Text
    ftpuserid = TxtUserName.Text
    ftpPassword = TxtPwd.Text

    Dim outputStream As FileStream = New FileStream((filepath + ("\\" + filename)), FileMode.Create)
    reqFTP = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(("ftp://" _
                        + (ftpserverip + ("/" + filename1))))), FtpWebRequest)
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    reqFTP.UseBinary = True
    reqFTP.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpuserid, ftpPassword)
    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(reqFTP.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)

    Dim ftpStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
    Dim cl As Long = response.ContentLength
    Dim bufferSize As Integer = 2048
    Dim readCount As Integer
    Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte((bufferSize) - 1) {}
    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)

    While (readCount > 0)
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount)
        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)

    End While
    ftpStream.Close()

    outputStream.Close()
    response.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

During run time when I click the button the control not entered to an click event

Comment: Is it a web application? Double click on the button in Visual Studio and than you can enter the code there.

Comment: you will go and read question clearly....

Comment: Have you tried setting the buttons AutoPostBack property set to true?

Comment: You posted the wrong code, this doesn't have anything to do with a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your code is not in the correct handler.

Double click the button on your form and make sure that the code is present within this. If not, just simpily copy and paste it in.

Hope this helps!